# Export Visio 2013 Stencil as vsx

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I have an application that says it can import Visio Stencils. However, it only supports the ".vsx"-File Format.

I have a .vss file that i'd like to import. Sadly, the other application really ONLY allows .vsx. I tried opening the .vss in Visio 2013 and saving it, however the file format is .vssx then and still not compatible. I tried to find out how to export as .vsx, but i found nothing...

How can i convert a .vss and .vssx file to .vsx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visio 2013 no longer supports the .vsx format. One answer would be get a version of Visio that does e.g. Visio 2003, 2007 or 2010. However, that is probably not going to be possible unless you have access to old versions or have an MSDN licence.

Comment: Thank you for your offer. Sadly, i was asking because the context of the question is the development of an application, that uses a flowchart-framework that is supposed to be able to import Visio Stencils.

I also got myself a Visio 2010 demo version and tried to convert the files, but the framework didn't load them correctly. So it seems it doesn't work however you look at it...

Anyhow, very confusing, since Word & Excel support saving anything into formats from 10+ years ago...

Comment: I'd assumed from your question that you wanted just a one-off conversion. I agree, destroying backward compatibilty by removing the .vsx format was inexcusable.

Comment: I tried keeping the question simple ;-) Thank you very much however for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while using Yed tool, but wanted to import visio stencils, some possible way I discovered, but didn't tested yet, is to go with vss to svg conversion, if that is option for you.

https://github.com/kakwa/libvisio2svg

UPDATE: I see now ONLY in your request, so assume SVG format is no go in your case, but lets leave this link here as others might found it useful.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Read update...